# CMS & Membership Sample Solr Schemas

Tags: solr, schema, solrj, solrcloud

Just wanted to know if anybody is aware of any sites that have sample or freely available solr schemas.
Would like to compare my membership and cms schemas in terms of structure and matedata. Would like to see how people use nested objects and embedded queries

Comment: The schema must be designed and adjusted to the specific use cases you have - which queries you want to answer and how you want to use Solr. There really isn't a one-fits-all way for schemas.

Comment: Hi MatsLindh. I agree with you, however, i wanted to check other implementations in terms of structures, schemas, nesting, field definition, collections etc. Would have just been nice to compare what I have against something else